# VS Code Icon not updated in Big Sur

Tags: dock, big-sur, icon

I'm on macOS 11.2.3 (20D91). I updated VS Code to the latest version which introduces [a new icon](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_updated-brand-icons-for-macos-big-sur).

Unfortunately, icon remains the same of before. I have already run `killall Dock` and `killall Finder` but things did not change.

Comment: Icon... where?  In the Dock?  In a Finder window?  I have to say, mine updated and it's ugly.  It's really unfortunate that developers don't have an easy way to provide multiple icons, so that those of us staying far far away from Big Sur's UI disaster don't have to look at the mess.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the current VS Code app first? You can then download it from https://code.visualstudio.com/Download, unzip it and drag it to the Applications folder. The Dock icon should update after starting VS Code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is "Bug Sur" in the title a pun or a typo?

Comment: @jaume just a typo (edited). No pun intended.

Comment: @MarcWilson the problem is in the Dock

Comment: Fixed with this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101014#issuecomment-808368475

Comment: Great news, could you add the steps to fix the icon problem with a reference to the source as an answer? You can then mark it as accepted to show other people with a similar issue that your issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed thanks to [this suggestion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101014#issuecomment-808368475)

From the link above:

1. Restart your dock via `killall Dock` in the terminal
2. Run these scripts in your terminal (which updates the timestamp of the icons):

   ```
   sudo touch /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app
   sudo touch /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Info.plist
   sudo touch /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/Code.icns
   killall Dock Finder
   ```

   *Note: For Insiders and Explorations, simply append \ -\ Insiders or \ -\ Exploration to each version name reference.*
3. Force the IconService cache to be rebuilt using [these steps](https://mjtsai.com/blog/2019/02/01/clearing-the-icon-services-cache-in-mojave/):

   1. Remove the main IconServices cache store:

      ```
      sudo rm -rfv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
      ```
   2. Remove the subsidiary store, which includes the Dock icon cache too:

      ```
      sudo find /private/var/folders/ \( -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -or -name com.apple.iconservices \) -exec rm -rfv {} \;
      ```
   3. Restart and give your Mac plenty of time to rebuild the caches.